# Spring Data JPA save many to many relation while creating the objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to optimize the following code. This piece of code is ran ~1000 times and with the combinations of other pieces of the code (that cannot be changed) will cause a serious performance problem.

Is there a way to reduce the number of database operations? I would put the additionalFilesSave outside the loop, to do it only once, but then the part about creating the ProductMAdditionalFilesEntities starts causing problem with the ID-s of additional files (since the ID-s of unsaved files are 0).

```
Set<AdditionalFilesEntity> additionalFilesEntities = productEntity.getAdditionalFilesEntities();

            if (p.getAdditionalFiles() != null) {
                for (AdditionalFile additionalFile : p.getAdditionalFiles()) {
                    AdditionalFilesEntity additionalFilesEntity = new AdditionalFilesEntity();
                    if (additionalFile.getFileType().equals("PICTURE")) {
                        additionalFilesEntity.setFileType(FileTypeEnum.PICTURE);
                    } else {
                        additionalFilesEntity.setFileType(FileTypeEnum.FILE);
                    }
                    additionalFilesEntity.setFileName(additionalFile.getFileName());
                    additionalFilesEntity.setFileDescription(additionalFile.getFileDescription());
                    additionalFilesEntity.setUrl(URLDecoder.decode(additionalFile.getFileUrl()));
                    additionalFilesEntities.add(additionalFilesEntity);
                }
            }

            additionalFilesRepository.save(additionalFilesEntities);

            for (AdditionalFilesEntity additionalFilesEntity : additionalFilesEntities) {
                pmf.add(new ProductMAdditionalFilesEntity(productEntity.getId(),
                    null,
                    additionalFilesEntity.getId()));
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered just using batch inserts with a simple `JdbcTemplate`? It looks what you are doing database wise is pretty simple.

Comment: Its is simple. A JSON with data comes in. list of products where each product can have a list of files. Product is aware fo files, but file isnt aware of product. How would one use JdbcTemplate for this? Also, with products there is a probability that it already exsists, so it only needs to update the data instead of insert.

Answer (score 1):

If `JdbcTemplate` is an option the following should be the general approach:

Insert the file using one of the [`JdbcTemplate.update()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-) variants.
Use a `KeyHolder` to obtain the id generated by the database.

Insert the reference to the product using the product id and the ids you got from the database in the first step.
If your database supports merge/upsert statements, this can probably be done in a single statement.
Otherwise, it's two statements.

This reduces the work to 2-3 statements per file.

This should be even faster if you can employ batch updates. 
Unfortunately, batch updates [don't work well with id generation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/6530).
You can always use batch updates for the second step. 
For the first one, you might be able to generate the id's on the Java side if you for example use UUIDs.

Comment: I proposed the idea to our architect and he said no. He said using the JdbcTemplates is going back in time by 10 years.

Comment: Now, that is an interesting "argument". ‍♂️

Comment: He seems to be supporting temporary tables. In postgresql there are temporary tables that are created at the beginning of transaction and removed at the end. But i cant seem to find a way to do it in JPA.

Comment: That is kind of funny, since JDBC and therefore `JdbcTemplate` would be exactly the right tool if you want to utilize such database specifics.